# VS2022 Quick add class

Tags: c#, class, shortcut, visual-studio-2022

I've bound ALT+INS to "Add Class" in VS (version 2019 and it remembered it for 2022 as well).
But it opens the old clunky "add file" dialog with class preselected, which is slow. I like the R# way where it just adds a file straight into your solution explorer.
I know there are Marketplace addons that do something similar; the Mads K one still seems to give a dialog. I want to be faster than a dialog.
Before I write my own extension, did I miss if this is a feature now in VS2022? If not, is there a good extension that does the R# thing?
No, installing R# is not an option, I only have 128Gb of memory on this Desktop unfortunately.

Comment: _”I only have 128Gb of memory on this Desktop unfortunately.”_ … ? … And this isn’t enough memory?  Are you possibly talking about talking about Hard Drive space? IMO 128GB of ram should be plenty of ram for just about anything.

Comment: @johnG Sorry its a subtle dig at the product when a few years ago, their mem consumption sky rocketed. I understand the joke might be missed by people not using those toolings though.

Comment: the speed of adding a .cs file is never bottleneck of programming efficiency. if you really need creating a lot of files, consider T4 templates.

Comment: @LeiYang - Be careful saying 'never' when you don't understand another person's workflow. Would be helpful if you could contribute towards the answer though rather than giving opinion about why my question is irrelevant to me.

Comment: so try to describe your particular workflow in the question? i'd like to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of using ReSharper or writing your own extension the only option is to go with TDD route e.g.

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

Where Customer does not exist. Pressing **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** to get either `Generate class Customer in new file` or `Generate new type`.

Option 1 is closest to what you are after.

Option 2 seems like `Generate new type` is the better option as one can indicate an existing or non-existing path which Visual Studio will generate rather than the first option which places the new file in the current path be it the project root folder or a sub-folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use add new item with: Shift + F2
Just type the name of the class and enter!

[image: Image of add new item dialog]